# Objective-C for iPhone - app crashing when using simple date commands

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm still learning Objective-C so forgive me if this is a simple amateur mistake, but I guess we all have to learn somehow.

Basically I have an app with a simple bit of text, at the header of the screen, which has been IBOutletted and called 'headerText'. I want this to read "Summary for February", replacing February with whatever month it is - so the month must be fetched dynamically.

```
   - (void)setHeaderText {
     NSString *headerTextTitle;
     NSString *monthString;
     NSDate *month;
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;

     month = [[NSDate alloc] init]; // Automatically fills in today's date
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
     monthString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:month];

     headerTextTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Summary for (%@)", monthString];
     headerText.text = headerTextTitle;

     [headerTextTitle release];
     [monthString release];
     [month release];
     [dateFormat release];
    }
```

I can obviously modify the text and stuff, but I find the app crashes whenever I call this method on viewDidLoad. Could anyone tell me what's wrong? I THINK it errors in this line here:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
```

Because when using breakpoints stuff goes a bit funny there. What am I doing wrong? I'm rather confused.

I appreciate the help!

Jack

EDIT: I'm now doing this:

```
month = [[NSDate alloc] init]; // Automatically fills in today's date
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    monthString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:month];
```

But it's still failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dateFormat is undefined for a start.

You need to initialise it, something like

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should alloc/init an NSDateFormatter before using it...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't release `monthString` as it is an autorelease object.

See [this](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-memory-management.html)

> #### Object Ownership
>
> Rule #1 – If you create an object using alloc or copy, you need to free that object.
>
> Rule #2 – If you didn’t create an object directly, don’t attempt to release the memory for the object.

Answer (score 1):

How about making it a little shorter by doing something like this:

```
- (void) setHeaderText
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter defaultFormatterBehavior];
    [formatter setDateFormat: @"MMMM"];
    headerText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"Summary for (%@)", [dateFormat stringFromDate: [NSDate date]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:

```
NSString *monthString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Had to be put in. Now it works fine :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  epatel's two answers are both crashing bug in this code.  

The month string you want to use was given to you by `[dateFormat stringFromDate:month];`.  There's no need to allocate one yourself.  Just get rid of the unbalanced release on month string.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I thought it was correct because it generated the results I wanted, and didn't crash or anything - thank you for pointing it out :)